# URGENT - How to fix a broken laptop charger/tell whether its the port?

Tags: laptop, charger

I still use my old laptop (asus r500v, ~4-5 years old) for work and university so I have a huge problem now: when I plugged in the charger it made a short buzzing sound and noe it isnt charging anymore. I took out the battery and switched sockets, it still doesnt charge, so it could be the charger or the port. Theres no shop near me that sells these chargers and ordering one off the internet would take up to 5 days - same as going to a repairstore and of course this happens  on a friday evening, so everything closed down until monday.

Now is there a way to tell whether its the plug or the port?

And does anybody know a quick fix that will at least allow me to get some of my files off the laptops harddrive? I got all my work files as well as my ~80% finished masters thesis exclusively on this laptop (dumb of me, i know).

A quick response would be much appreciated, as I cannot work or finish my thesis without these files.. 
Thank you to anyone kind enough to help me!

Comment: If you could find someone with the same battery then you could use that.... but no, there's no quick fixes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am positive that I am sooner going to find someone with the technilogical knowledge to help me than someone with the exakt same laptop model as me.

Comment: No-one can test this for you online. You need, at minimum, one spare laptop & one spare PSU, to even do simple consumer-level 'swap it & see' testing.

Comment: From what you have said (about buzzing) it sounds more likely to be a charger issue then a laptop one. Also, have you looked for a generic charger? You can use - or at least limp by with a charger of similar  voltage (withing 0.5 volt) and the same or greater current rating and compatible plug (or spluce your existing one).

Comment: I am aware, that nobody can solve the problem itself for me online, I was hoping to get creative ideas from you guys to sort of work around the problem to at least power it up for a few minutes to transfer files. Seeing as this apparently cant be done, I am going to have to live with not being able to use my laptop for a week. The important thing was having my files, which I am going to extract from my hd by taking it out of the case and connecting it to another pc. Thank you for helping me eitherway.

Answer (score 1):

You can find universal chargers at an electronics store (BestBuy, Frys, etc.). They are not cheap, but they will at least let you know if it is the charger or the laptop. Your work or university IT department may have one you can at least use for testing.

If the drive is not encrypted, you can pull it from the laptop and put it in a USB enclosure or plug it directly in to another computer. If you have any local computer shops they should be able to do that for you fairly easily.

When you get up and running again, you might want to start keeping your thesis files in a cloud service, like DropBox or Google Drive.

Comment: Fair enough. The point is that many people are not aware there are “universal” laptop chargers. I’ve seen them at stores that just have an electronics department as well.

Comment: A genuine "thank you" for helping. The problem remains until monday, when all the shops open up again, but at least a 3-5 day shipment can likely be avoided. As for the harddrive, i've just taken it out of my laptop and will extract my files from there. Especially for my work and uni files I am going to get an external hd. Again thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

I can't answer about the charger / plug. But, about your data, the only way to recover files from an out-of-order computer is by extracting the hard drive and plug it into a working computer. You just need a SATA cable and a computer power supply with its cable.